# Ableton Live and Reaktor snapshots overwrite

Tags: synthesizer, ableton-live, vst, plug-ins, reaktor

So I built my custom synth with Reaktor. Being used to produce several drum sounds, I have usually different instances of it on different Ableton Live tracks.

The problem is snapshot saving. Apparently Ableton Live does not store the current settings of the synth (first problem), so I have to use the snapshot capability.
But, even if I append the snapshots, the entire snapshots settings get overwritten if I save the synth.

**Example problem:**
I created a kick on one instance of my synth, I store the snapshot and I save the ensemble. Then, I open the other instance of my synth that had a snare drum, I slightly change the snare drum and I store the snapshot. When I save, the ensemble settings of the kick (in the other instance) are of course overwritten.

The only way trough export to add a snapshot and export the bank at each small change I make. This is very impractical. Another "solution" would be to save an ensemble for each instance of my synth that I want to use in my project. This is also extremely cumbersome.

I think that my way of working (several instances of one synth in an Ableton Live project) is very common. So, how do people manage with every small change? Maybe there is a way to avoid storing snapshot and let Ableton Live completely save the settings of my ensemble? But how?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.